# How do I make a custom class that's serializable with dataclasses.asdict()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to use a dataclass as a (more strongly typed) dictionary in my application, and found this strange behavior when using a custom type subclassing `list` within the dataclass. I'm using Python 3.11.3 on Windows.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

class CustomFloatList(list):
    def __init__(self, args):
        for i, arg in enumerate(args):
            assert isinstance(arg, float), f"Expected index {i} to be a float, but it's a {type(arg).__name__}"

        super().__init__(args)

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, l: list[float]):
        return cls(l)

@dataclass
class Poc:
    x: CustomFloatList

p = Poc(x=CustomFloatList.from_list([3.0]))
print(p)  # Prints Poc(x=[3.0])
print(p.x)  # Prints [3.0]
print(asdict(p))  # Prints {'x': []}
```

This does not occur if I use a regular list[float], but I'm using a custom class here to enforce some runtime constraints.

How do I do this correctly?

I'm open to just using `.__dict__` directly, but I thought `asdict()` was the more "official" way to handle this

A simple modification makes the code behave as expected, but is slightly less efficient:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

class CustomFloatList(list):
    def __init__(self, args):
        dup_args = list(args)
        for i, arg in enumerate(dup_args):
            assert isinstance(arg, float), f"Expected index {i} to be a float, but it's a {type(arg).__name__}"

        super().__init__(dup_args)

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, l: list[float]):
        return cls(l)

@dataclass
class Poc:
    x: CustomFloatList

p = Poc(x=CustomFloatList.from_list([3.0]))
print(p)
print(p.x)
print(asdict(p))
```

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the way it recurses into values to look for other dataclasses. But I'm not sure why it causes this result.

Comment: The fact that it silently coerces to an empty list feels like a bug, perhaps?

Comment: `asdict` makes a deep copy, and as part of that it creates a temporary **generator** over the iterable to be passed back to the original type's constructor (here, `CustomFloatList.__init__`). Since it creates a generator, and you `enumerate` over the generator, by the time you do `super().__init__` the generator is exhausted.

Comment: Interesting, let me see if duplicating the iterator solves my problem. Is this behavior documented anywhere? I couldn't find a mention of it in `help(asdict)`

Comment: No, it's an implementation detail. I only understood this mechanism by looking at the source code - see the function `dataclasses.py::_asdict_inner`.

Comment: The prob lem is you are **consuming the iterator you pass to `CustomFloatList`**

Comment: This begs the questions: Should the behavior be documented? Is it a bug?

Comment: The basic problem is that your subclass doesn't act like the real `list()` constructor. It accepts a generator as the argument, yours doesn't work correctly when given a generator.

Comment: It's not specific to `asdict()`, it's a bug in your subclass.

Comment: @Barmar `list(<generator>)` also consumes a generator

Comment: Got it, what would you suggest as an alternative to the naive solution I posted in the question body?

Comment: @dROOOze sure, but it *adds each element to itself* while it does that, the OP's code doesn't.

Comment: @dROOOze The difference is that the `list()` constructor only tries to process the generator once, his tries twice.

Comment: I don't know what `list(<generator>)` actually does. To be honest, based on your implementation, I would call `super().__init__(args)` first, then validate the elements by iterating over `self`. This is assuming you're not going to get a whole heap of validation assertion errors in your runtime code.

Comment: @dROOOze it basically just calls `self.extend(data)` always, and that basically jsut loops over `data` and does `self.append` in the general case (it optimizes for the case where you give it another `list` or a `tuple`)

Comment: Side note: `assert` is removed in optimized Python code.  `raise TypeError(msg)` instead.  And +1 for @dROOOze calling `super` first and iterating over `self` for validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [source code of `asdict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d334122d2295a4863384676a3ce313a831b12335/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1364), you'll see that passes a generator expression that recursively calls itself on the elements of a list when it encounters a list:

```
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        # Assume we can create an object of this type by passing in a
        # generator (which is not true for namedtuples, handled
        # above).
        return type(obj)(_asdict_inner(v, dict_factory) for v in obj)
```

But *your implementation depletes any iterator it gets in `__init__` before the `super` call*.

Don't do that. You'll have to "cache" the values if you want to use the superclass constructor. Something like:

```
class CustomFloatList(list):
    def __init__(self, args):
        args = list(args)
        for i, arg in enumerate(args):
            assert isinstance(arg, float), f"Expected index {i} to be a float, but it's a {type(arg).__name__}"

        super().__init__(args)
```

Or perhaps:

```
class CustomFloatList(list):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super().__init__(args)
        for i, arg in enumerate(self):
            if not isinstance(arg, float):
                raise TypeError(f"Expected index {i} to be a float, but it's a {type(arg).__name__}")
```

Comment: Would it be a bug to do `self = args` (for the cached `args`) instead of `super().__init__` to avoid repeating the constructor?

Comment: @ijustlovemath `self = args` doesn't do anything useful. It assigns whatever you pass to `args` to the *local variable `self`*. Without calling `list.__init__`, or manually adding each element, the list will be empty

Comment: Is there any way to do this without incurring the cost of the cache? Only asking out of interest, not genuine performance concerns

Comment: @ijustlovemath yeah look at the second approach, it won't require the use of an auxiliary list, although likely, underneath the hood it will require the same amount of memory, since you are re-sizing the internal buffer as the `CustomFloatList` grows.

Comment: Is it really safe to append before initializing the superclass?

Comment: @Barmar yeah I'm fairly certain it's fine. Almost certainly, this is what happens in `list.__init__` in the general case (probably there are optimizations when you are working with `list` or `tuple` types, and the buffers are efficiently copied, if I had to guess)

Comment: The built-in list class is written in C, although it might allow this specifically to support subclassing. I guess it allocates the underlying data structure in its `__new__()` method.

Comment: I think @dROOOze's solution of initializing the superclass *first* is actually most compelling, and doesn't come with the ambiguities of "can we really call `.append` before initializing the superclass?"

Comment: @Barmar yeah, so, `__init__` basically just calls `.extend` on the argument, which just does what I had expected, `.append` in a loop for arbitrary iterables, with special fast approaches if you have another `list` or a `tuple`

Comment: @ijustlovemath yeah, that is probably safer, but I would just go with the `args = list(args)` approach, personally

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga would you mind editing your second solution to call the superclass constructor first, and performing validation by using `enumerate` over `self`?

Comment: I meant `super().__init__(args)` Instead of using `.append`, was my intention! Sorry if that was unclear

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to `asdict()`. The problem is that your subclass is not compatible with the real `list` class, because the `__init__()` method doesn't work correctly when the input is a generator. You can see the problem more simply with

```
print(CustomFloatList(float(x) for x in range(10)))
```

This will print an empty list.

You consume the generator in the loop that checks that all the elements are floats, then pass the empty generator when calling `super().__init__()`.

Change it so it extracts the contents once.

```
class CustomFloatList(list):
    def __init__(self, args):
        temp = list(args)
        for i, arg in enumerate(temp):
            assert isinstance(arg, float), f"Expected index {i} to be a float, but it's a {type(arg).__name__}"

        super().__init__(temp)

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, l: list[float]):
        return cls(l)
```